# Play a video on the default media player in Universal App

Tags: c#, xaml, mediaelement, win-universal-app

I would need to execute a function that plays a video in the default media player(Phone or Tab) from Universal Apps that uses Xaml and C#.

I don't want to embed the player .Actually my need is to open a new window with the default player and tell it to play the selected file.

All samples  that I've saw in Google  are to create an embedded player or send to a device Only.

Could you please give some suggestion for this issue. Thanks in Advance.